# Child carousel inside parent carousel slick js

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Every slider slide has its own child slider which has independence regardless to its parent. Now the view which I want is following layout.

[image]

This is what I have achieved so far. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/675/)

```
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 0,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});

$('.slider-mini').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

Comment: I think you should start a bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you are looking for:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 0,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  onBeforeChange: (slider) => {
     console.log('onBeforeChange', slider);
     slider.$slider.addClass('sliding');
  },
  onAfterChange: (slider) => {
     console.log('onAfterChange', slider);
     slider.$slider.removeClass('sliding');
  }

})
$('.slider-mini').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.black {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}

.slick-center {
  border: solid 0px blue
}

.red-mini {
  background: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.green-mini {
  background: green;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.yellow-mini {
  background: yellow;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.black-mini {
  background: black;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.slider .slick-prev {
  background: black
}

.slider .slick-next {
  background: black;
  z-index: 5;
}
.slider-mini {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 640px;
  margin-left: -215px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-center .slider-mini {
  visibility: visible;
}
.slider-mini .slick-prev {
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
}
.slider-mini .slick-next {
  right: 0;
  transition: opacity 250ms;
}

.slider.sliding .slick-prev, .slider.sliding .slick-next {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="slider-mini">
      <div class="red-mini">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="red-mini">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="red-mini">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="red-mini">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="red-mini">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="green">

    </div>
    <div class="slider-mini">
      <div class="green-mini">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="green-mini">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="green-mini">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="green-mini">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="green-mini">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="yellow">
      
    </div>
    <div class="slider-mini">
        <div class="yellow-mini">
          1
        </div>


        <div class="yellow-mini">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="yellow-mini">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="yellow-mini">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="yellow-mini">
          5
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="black">
      
    </div>
    <div class="slider-mini">
        <div class="black-mini">
          1
        </div>


        <div class="black-mini">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="black-mini">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="black-mini">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="black-mini">
          5
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can we stop arrow from moving for child carousel

Comment: @Carlos edited my answer to hide child arrows while sliding

Answer (score 1):

I went for another approach than the answer provided by thedude, which might be interesting to you as well.

[JSFiddle with my answer](https://jsfiddle.net/Glodenox/muyhj41b/8/)

*Note:* Observe that I've upgraded the Slick library to 1.6.0, so the slick-theme.css is also needed now (unless you want to completely replace it with something of your own)

I've changed the structure of the HTML a bit to put all mini sliders in a `div.mini-sliders` and turned that element into a slider that can't be adjusted manually. By then setting the `asNavFor` option of the top slider to point this slider, the top slider automatically moves the mini-sliders at the same time, which looks nicer as the previous mini-slider doesn't disappear abruptly. I've also made the arrows disappear when the slider changes as requested.

I ran into an issue with the buttons for the mini sliders as these were displayed outside of their visible area and became visible in the sibling sliders, but considering that your mock-up shows the arrows overlapping with the slider, a bit of CSS easily fixed that while also matching your design. If you want to make the buttons appear outward more, you'd need to increase the margin on the slides in the `.mini-sliders .slick-slide .slick-slide` selector slightly.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 0,
  swipeToSlide: true,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  asNavFor: '.mini-sliders',
  cssEase: 'linear'
});

$('.mini-sliders').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  arrows: false,
  draggable: false,
  touchMove: false,
  dots: false
}).on('beforeChange', function() {
  $('.mini-sliders button').hide();
}).on('afterChange', function() {
  $('.mini-sliders button').show();
});

$('.mini-sliders .slick-slide').slick({
  slidesToShow: 5,
  dots: false,
  swipeToSlide: true,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
}).on('beforeChange', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.slider, .mini-sliders {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider .slick-slide {
  height: 200px;
}

.mini-sliders .slick-slide .slick-slide {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  height: 80px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.slider .slick-prev {
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.slider .slick-next {
  right: -10px;
}

.mini-sliders .slick-slide .slick-prev {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.mini-sliders .slick-slide .slick-next {
  right: 0;
}

.slick-arrow {
  background: black !important;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.black {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="black"></div>
</div>
<div class="mini-sliders">
  <div>
    <div class="red">1</div>
    <div class="red">2</div>
    <div class="red">3</div>
    <div class="red">4</div>
    <div class="red">5</div>
    <div class="red">6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="green">1</div>
    <div class="green">2</div>
    <div class="green">3</div>
    <div class="green">4</div>
    <div class="green">5</div>
    <div class="green">6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="yellow">1</div>
    <div class="yellow">2</div>
    <div class="yellow">3</div>
    <div class="yellow">4</div>
    <div class="yellow">5</div>
    <div class="yellow">6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="black">1</div>
    <div class="black">2</div>
    <div class="black">3</div>
    <div class="black">4</div>
    <div class="black">5</div>
    <div class="black">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```